# Set the sum and product

Tags: code-golf, number

Given two positive reals \$a\$ and \$b\$, output some positive reals \$r_i\$, such that \$\sum r_i=a\$ and \$\prod\left(r_i+1\right)=b\$. You can assume that it's possible. You can also assume that your float type have infinite precision.

Test cases:

```
2,3 => 2
2,4 => 1,1 or 1/2,(sqrt(57)+9)/12,(9-sqrt(57))/12 or etc.
2,5 => 1/3,1/2,2/3,1/2 or etc.
2,8 => (undefined behavior)
2,2 => (undefined behavior)
e,2e => 1,e-1 or etc. (e is natural base, though any number>1 work)
3,e^3 => (undefined behavior) (It's possible to get as close as you want to e^3, but not reaching)
```

Shortest code wins.

## Notes

- Given the assumption with infinite precision, you can't solve arbitrary equation if your language doesn't have such functions(you can still use functions like `Solve` in Mathematica to solve such). In this case, some forms may have solution mathematically but you can't work it out, e.g. \$p,p,p,...,p,q\$ where \$p\$ and \$q\$ are reals. (At least software don't provide exact solution for `x*x*x*y=5,3*x+y=7`)

Comment: Maybe add a test case where \$a\$/\$b\$/both are non-integers? Or even, such that \$a \ne 2\$

Comment: I would also recommend a case where `a` and `b` aren't rational, or the answer can't be rational, since I notice you mentioned all real numbers. I suspect this challenge may be significantly harder for transcendental inputs, though I'm not sure.

Comment: Can you please add a plain English spec for the benefit of those of us who can't read mathematical notation?

Comment: @Shaggy \$\prod (1+r_i)\$ seems hard to express in that plain English to easily get understood

Comment: How about? "Add one to each number on the list, and then take its product"

Comment: Could you please confirm that `2,0` is an invalid output for the first test case?

Comment: @Arnauld output some **positive** reals

Answer (score 15):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 67 bytes

```hs
a#b|h<-a/2,c<-sqrt$(1+h)^2-b,c>0=h+c:[h-c|h>c]|l<-(a/2)#sqrt b=l++l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY7LboQwDEX3@QprhgURCYUAU6iAL5hdl3SmCgE1qOHRENQN/06N1MW1fKXjI2u5fvfGHIe8trsuuXwRTJV8/bHO8@NA06fgLVN1VOlAvTWaq13X6rGbkvvI0utJQluZIDDHKIepWjb37ux9uviN/RweDNZt9HGjDBY7d5tyZwtiSj@mS12beV7IOapuJtBI1j5KPsoFbC@78He23Vp69Vfv7sPUEzC9A1vhswRtw4Quhn6w7N/t@WjGA0uRReshICECUkxGRPga5yI/k2ZFlGaQhWlyy25nijiPCpJAXPwB)

Based on [this solution of Delfad0r](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225850/20260), who also saved 1 byte off this

We first try to find a two-element solution with \$r_1+r_2=a\$ and \$(r_1+1)(r_2+1)=b\$, which we do by solving a quadratic equation. If we get real solutions, we're done. (If one solution is zero, we remove it and output a singleton.)

If this quadratic isn't solvable in the reals, we replace \$a \to a/2\$ and \$b \to \sqrt{b}\$ and solve from there. If we find a solution to this, then duplicating the list (that is, repeating each element a second time) gives a solution to the original problem, since this doubles the sum and squares the product of numbers-plus-one. We recursively make these substitutions until we simplify \$(a,b)\$ to ones that give a two-element solution.

We show that this process always reaches a solution. For the problem to be solvable, we must have \$b < e^a\$, which follows directly from \$\sum r_i=a\$ and \$\prod\left(r_i+1\right)=b\$ along with \$e^{r_i}>r_i+1\$. Since \$e^a\$ is the increasing limit of \$(1+a/N)^N\$ as \$N \to \infty\$, the bound \$b < e^a\$ implies that \$b < (1+a/N)^N\$, or equivalently that \$b^{1/N} < 1+a/N\$, for sufficiently large \$N\$. By choosing \$N=2^n\$ as a large power of \$2\$, doing \$n-1\$ steps of the substitution \$a \to a/2\$ and \$b \to \sqrt{b}\$ gives us \$a' = 2a/N\$ and \$b' = b^{2/N}\$, which we've shown satisfy \$\sqrt{b'} < 1 + a'/2\$.

This is exactly what we need to have real solutions for \$r_1+r_2=a\$ and \$(r_1+1)(r_2+1)=b\$, which gives a quadratic with discriminant \$(1+a/2)^2-b\$. It solutions are $$r  = a/2 \pm \sqrt{(1+a/2)^2-b}$$

Comment: Great explanation, thanks.

Comment: [67 bytes](https://tio.run/##LY5NboQwDEb3OYU1w4KIQCHAFCrgBLPrkjJVCFGDyl9DUDdzd@pIXXyWLT8/WYv9W03TeYpr/9RVKF44k1W4/xjr@Umg6YOHPZNNXOtAvrU6lE/dyM6hPrL06kjocRvocxbjUm@Hfbfmvlz81nyOHYP9mH3sKIPNrMMhrZuChNKP5dI007puxJV6WAm0gvVdFc5iA6PEEP2uZtgrr/lS9j4uisCkLJganyVoGxd0MfSDYf9uz0czHhiKLFpPDinhkGFywqPXpOCFS5aXcZZDHmXpLb@5lEkRlySFpPwD "Haskell – Try It Online") (also, amazing answer!).

Answer (score 8):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <sup><s>102</s>…</sup> 95 bytes

- -6 bytes thanks to [xnor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20260/xnor) (also, go upvote [his amazing answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225866/82619)!).

```hs
a#b|m<-until(\m->(1+a/m)**m>=b)(+2)2=filter(>0)[a/m+sqrt((1+a/m)^2-b**(2/m))*(-1)**i|i<-[1..m]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY/BboMwEETv/gorzcEGTLGBFCTgC3LrkdDKFLe1ahtqjHrJv9NFymFWs9qZJ@23XH@UMfsun8a7bdjmgjbkZllHeCyfLY0i27UjJbGgov3UJihPuoz2cIvXXx/II/cm2BhFRIClEWEcivquG9bzNLXDsFupXbts4TX4qzuR3r/rIcHrZgk4muDFz9P2EY4t5pTe3KnrzDwv6BjtNCPcy2QcGmblgr2SU/o3@2ltzt2XClftFMJGBexbeAQBTTtgJcDHPnmwzwTIUPAUskDdBc6RwAWoRCJ94ZWoDhVlnRUlLtMiv5SXQzWvshrlmNf/)

The relevant function is `(#)` which takes as input `a` and `b` as described in the statement.

Comment: Nice solution. I think [this works for 96](https://tio.run/##LY/BboMwEETv/gorzcE2mMQGUpAwX5Bbj4RWpqDWKjbUGPXCv9NFymFWM9rZJ@23Xn6Gcdx3/dJtnVI6EqrR7WYrvrpgRvKwvCYi0hdLGbO16iiJJJVQutho@fWBPLfvkneMEQmWMsIF1M1mKt6IJLFtu1ttnJrX8Bb83Z1I4z9MG@NltQQcjfHsp379DEeKBKUPd6rrcZpmdAzVTwg3Ou7ails9Yz/oPvmbfL9U5/prCHfjBoTHIWCv4BMENOOAFQMf@/jJPhMgw4Gn0AXqLnGKJM5AOZLJqyhkcSjLy2uW4zzJ0lt@O1SK4lqiFIvyHw "Haskell – Try It Online"). But, I wonder if it would be shorter to use that the condition on `m` that `(1+a/m)**m>=b` is equivalent to the `...` in `d=sqrt$...` being non-negative, and so somehow combine these.

Comment: @xnor Thanks! I can't believe I always forget the existence of `until` .-. . I was going to try golfing a bit more and add an explanation once I woke up (i.e. now), but you've already done a better job then I ever could.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>32</s> 31 bytes

```
ḷ‘ɼ_’;N};1Ær½ßH}¥/}x®$ÆiṪṪƊ?,ḟ0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hju2PGmac3BP/qGGmtV@tteHhtqJDew/P96g9tFS/tuLQOpXDbZkPd64ComNd9joPd8w3AOkxOLTy/Y6@o5Me7pxh/ahhjoKuncKjhrnWh5frg8VUNCO5DI0f7uhKNtJxUDy26VHTmkeNO6wPt///H22sYxSrE20CJk3BpJGeuaGFkYWOqZ6JsZmpWSwA)

A full program taking two arguments, `b` and `a` in that order. Implements [@xnor’s algorithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225866/42248), so be sure to upvote that one too! Uses recursion to find real roots to a quadratic equation of the form \$x^2 - w x + (y - w - 1) = 0\$ where \$w = \frac{a}{2 ^ n}\$ and \$y = b ^ \frac{1}{2n} \$ for some non-negative integer \$n\$.

### Explanation

```
ḷ‘ɼ                              | Increment the register, then revert to the original left argument (i.e. b)
   _                             | b - a
    ’                            | Subtract 1
     ;N}                         | Concatenate to -a
        ;1                       | Concatenate to 1
          Ær                     | Roots of polynomial with terms (b - a - 1, -a, 1)
                      ÆiṪṪƊ?     | Does the last root havecan imaginary component?
                ¥/}         ,    | - If yes, do the following using the original arguments to this link:
            ½ßH}                 |   - Call the current link recursively with the square root of the left argument and half the right argument
                   x®$           | - If not, repeat each term the number of times indicated by the register
                             ḟ0  | Filter out zeros
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 52 bytes

```
ＮθＮη≔¹ζＷ›ηＸ⊕∕θ⊗ζ⊗ζ≦⊕ζＦζＩΦＥ²⁺∕θ⊗ζ×∨λ±¹₂⁻Ｘ⊕∕θ⊗ζ²Ｘη∕¹ζκ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVA9j8IwDN37Kzw6Um6gAwvTCXSnDkDF3R8IxdCINGnzARJ/PucCJ4HEgAfLz/bzs920yjdOmZwr26e4St2WPA5iVjziVhSfIeiDxYmECxfPrTYE@O1JxbEuoXZnDirbeOrIRtrhQp/0jnCQsHBpazhzEUI8IwFL1d9HP3BvInvngbug9tpGnKsQ8UubUY9JWLKmSeG1jIRf3VHAtUcjYUUHXhMnY/5nSMrTxrmIS22Z//7ipfg/k@@9N13/cTMJR/aznMtimj9O5g8) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Basically another port of @xnor's answer.

```
ＮθＮη≔¹ζ
```

Input \$ a \$ and \$ b \$ and start counting the number of repetitions of the output that we need.

```
Ｗ›ηＸ⊕∕θ⊗ζ⊗ζ≦⊕ζ
```

Keep incrementing (doubling also works of course, but it's not strictly necessary) the number of repetitions while \$ b > (1 + \frac a {2n}) ^ {2n} \$. (This explains why \$ b < e^a \$.)

```
Ｆζ
```

Repeat the output the appropriate number of times...

```
ＩΦＥ²⁺∕θ⊗ζ×∨λ±¹₂⁻Ｘ⊕∕θ⊗ζ²Ｘη∕¹ζκ
```

... output up to two non-zero solutions to the quadratic.

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES10), 93 bytes

This is really just a port of [@xnor's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225866/58563).

Expects `(a)(b)`.

```javascript
a=>g=(b,r=1,x=(q=a/=2)+(d=(++q*q-b)**.5))=>x?Array(r).fill(a-d?[x,a-d]:x).flat():g(b**.5,r*2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fU5JboNAELz7FX2I5G4YJqyOFw1WDnkFQvKwObYIAwOOiCzeToY4yjGHUpdqadVVfso@15d2cBpVlHMlZinis8CMaeGxUWAn5LPwycZCoG13VudkZFk8IhLxeHzVWn6hJl5d6hqlUxyTkZmT7kej1XJA2p8xWwpMWz7NhwQS8BkEkLIHC/9Y9Mv4i7f1twvCaOeGkXF4GGyizYKdt3V3j2DAwDMU0hWvlH6T@TtiApJBBimBiOG@AtBlDwIqlIQZHYyQq6ZXdclrdcZT8nQ3AX5VlwbXsKYpBceJob99mNLD02Vxy0vElkH@87UFG3IGLk0MWq2MO/wXtgC9pUFmLU0ns2Gi@Rs)